# HTML to PDF css style not working

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, a, ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: #000;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<page format="A4" orientation="L" backcolor="#fff" style="font: arial;">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</page>
```

The "style" tag not working. Where is the problem! It's my first time to style a pdf in a php file. Thanks!

Comment: which tool are you using to generate the pdf file ?

Comment: use inline style in all elements

Comment: I don't now because it's been make it before i want to style it.
http://first-estates.com/property/printView/1730 this is the pdf

Comment: @Sanjay Gohil I want to style it with "style" tag

Comment: `style="font: arial;"` is wrong. The syntax is `style="font-family: arial;"`

Comment: @shockwave so............. solution ?? ^ where are we with this question? ^^

Comment: Thanks for the correction! The real problem is why "style" tag not working!? I don't want to use inline style in all elements!